# How do I read numbers only from an array that has numbers and letters using C?

Tags: c, arrays, file, text, int

I'm new here.
I have a text file that reads:

```
6
<cr>
R 0
R 1
R 4
R 36
R 0
R 4
```

**/edited/** This is what I have. I want to read each line into an array so that I can convert that array into an integer so I can print only the numbers of whichever line I want later.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <string.h>


    int main()
    {
        FILE *fr;   /*declares file pointer*/
        int i, j, num[32];
        char input_file[32], line[32];

        fr = fopen(input_file, "r");
        if(fr != NULL){

            while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fr) != NULL){
                for(i=0;i<strlen(line);i++){
                    if(line[i] >= '0' && line[i] <= '9'){
                        num[i] = line[i] - '0';
                    }
                i++;
                                printf("%d\n", num[i]);
            }
            fclose(fr);
        }
        else{
            perror(input_file);
        }
    }
```

I'm not getting any errors but it isn't printing the right thing; this is what it prints:

```
-370086
-370086
-370086
-370086
-370086
-370086
-370086
-370086
```

Comment: I would have used a structure instead of a char array if I was wanting to have different datatypes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use single quotes around a character to get it's actual byte value, so you can use that to check if a character is in the range you want.

Rather than using strcpy, you want to run through the characters in your line one at a time, accepting the ones you want, something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++)
{
    if(line[i] >= '0' && line[i] <= '9')
    {
        // this is a good character, add it to the array in the appropriate place
    }
}
```

Converting to an integer is something you should be able to work out, once you consider that '0' is the value 48 in decimal and [look at the table here](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Note, this looks a bit like homework, hence my answer does not give you everything you need — hopefully it gives you what you need to work it out though! Good luck.

Comment: there is a each of those are on different lines. the first line is a '6' the next line is '<cr>', the next is 'R 0', and so on....Will that loop work for that as well?

Comment: Instead of the explicit range check, why not just use `isdigit`?

Comment: I did that with getc and I had it print out every number. I don't need all of them; just the one starting at the first 0. And I didn't know how to bypass the 6.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I was aiming for the more general case in case he needed to check anything else. @oldbutnew Think about using a boolean variable as a flag, intialise it to `false`, and it stays `false` until you hit a 0, and while it's false you don't add to the array ;)

Comment: @LaceySnr I edited my program and I still can't get it to act right. I'm guessing I went wrong with trying to convert the line to an int.

Comment: How big is your array (num)? Also, be aware that the way you loop you need two indexes, when you find a digit, `i` will be 2, meaning you're writing into `num[2]` when you've not written in to either of the first two slots. Apologies for not providing more detail, but I find leading people in the direction is more beneficial in the long run!